# Inequalities using AM-GM

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Use the AM-GM inequality to prove $(5xy + 6y)^3$ ≥ $1215xy^3$ for all real numbers $x, y > 0.$

Not sure if I was on the right track but so for my understanding is:

since there is a power of 3 on the left we need 3 numbers

so you have $5xy + 3y + 3y$ ≥ $3(5x \times 3y \times 3y)^3$

bit stuck after this, or am I completely on the wrong track?

Comment: Note that you can cancel out the $y^3$.

Answer (score 2):

$5xy+3y+3y \geq 3(5xy*3y*3y)^{1/3}$ now if you raise both sides to the power 3 we get the result.

Comment: if i continue on that i would get $1215xy^2$ which isnt the right answer

Comment: Sorry i lost one $y$ from $xy$ now it should be ok.